# Sparse Matrix Library for GPU

Tags: sparse-matrix, gpu, software-recommendation

Does anyone know a good library that implements basic sparse matrix operations such as transpose, SpMV eigenvalues, etc. in GPU (cuda/OpenCL)?

Comment: Well, there's [Cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/), and for SpMV, there's this [technical report by NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_research_pub_001.html), but I'm skeptical of doing sparse linear algebra on GPUs (see [On the limits of GPU acceleration](http://static.usenix.org/event/hotpar10/tech/full_papers/main.pdf) by Vuduc, et al, whose work is reputable). You're probably better off trying to do the sparse linear algebra on CPUs.

Comment: Hi zimbra, welcome to scicomp!  Can you give a few more details about your application domain, expected problem sizes, and whether you would like to take advantages of multiple GPUs on distributed nodes (like a GPU-based cluster or supercomputer)?

Answer (score 3):

Check [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/viennacl-about.html). I use that library in many projects to improve performance of sparse operations and I am very pleased with the results. Remember that using GPU makes sense only for relatively large size of the jobs. Otherwise, it is not cost-effective.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [cupy](https://cupy.dev/). It supports basically all common sparse formats along with the common operations.

Answer (score 1):

The [cuSPARSE library](https://developer.nvidia.com/cusparse) is the official library developed by Nvidia and comes with the CUDA SDK, it implements a lot of sparse matrix operations.